# Resend email with try catch cause memory limit exceeded?

Tags: yii2

My server connection is looks like unstable cause of that sometime it successfully send email, and sometimes it fail.

The error says

```
Swift_TransportException

Connection to ssl://in-v3.mailjet.com:465 Timed Out
```

With above condition I try to change the code to resend email if exception is catched.

Here is my code in controller.

```
//this line after import class
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

public function resend_on_error($tried)
{
  try{
    $message = Yii::$app->mail->compose();
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
      $message->setFrom('from@domain.com');
    } else {
      $message->setFrom(Yii::$app->user->identity->email);
    }
    $message->setTo(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
    ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
    ->setTo("mymail@gmail.com")
    ->setSubject('Reset Password '.$tried)
    ->setHtmlBody($this->renderAjax('//email/_konten',['content'=>'goes here']))
    ->send();
     return 1;

  }catch(\Swift_TransportException $e){
    $this->resend_on_error($tried++);
  }
}

public function actionEmail()
{
  $tried = 1;
  if($this->resend_on_error($tried) == 1){
      return "send success";
  }
}
```

But I got this

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your running out of memory on the php side. Check memory_limit in the php config and set it temporary higher. The question is, why is your server consume such amount of memory?

Comment: @R13e because resend email with my above code, am I right?

Comment: Possible, but I dont think it is the cause. If I understand it correct, the resend process would only tried to allocate 20480 bytes. Thats not much at all.

Comment: @R13e increase memory limit doesn't make it work. any suggestion?

Comment: I think your code produces a loop and because of that you run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it obvious? You are catching the SSL timeout exception, but you immediately run the same function again and the same exception gets thrown, this loop occurs til it runs out of memory.

You do increment `$tried`,  but you dont check its value. I think you should try sending the mail 5 times, if it still.doesnt work something must be terribly broken and needs technical attention, in that case, catch SwiftTransport exception and throw another one to the end user.